# Stormpath AngularJS email verification link requires authentication

Tags: angularjs, stormpath

I'm trying to setup the email verification workflow for stormpath + angularjs. After I click on the verification link sent to my email, I am redirected to `http://localhost:3000/register/verify?sptoken=4rxDhXLpvcNj7AUzSvYIDL`. This is the expected url according to the [tutorial](http://docs.stormpath.com/angularjs/guide/register.html). The problem is the url requires the user to be authenticated. This is self-defeating because a user only gets authenticated after logging in with registered credentials that are verified via email.

One step in the tutorial I was confused about and which may be the cause of the issue is **Add the sptoken Paremeter**. It says to add the parameter `'/register/verify?sptoken'` to the `url` property in the `emailVerification` controller. This didn't make sense to me because controller file created by angular generator is practically empty and shouldn't affect routing, so instead, I did this for the `emailVerification` state in the `$stateProvider` module.

Besides this, the other steps were straightforward. I tried setting `sp: { authenticate: false }` for the `emailVerification` state, but this didn't solve the problem.

**Angular app.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name clientApp
 * @description
 * # clientApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('clientApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'xeditable',
    'ng-sortable',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'stormpath',
    'stormpath.templates',
    'ui.router'
  ])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
.state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterCtrl' 
})
.state('emailVerification', {
    url: '/register/verify?sptoken',
    templateUrl: 'views/emailverification.html',
    controller: 'EmailverificationCtrl'
})
.state('passwordResetRequest', {
    url: '/password/requestReset',
    templateUrl: 'views/passwordresetrequest.html',
    controller: 'PasswordResetRequestCtrl'
})
.state('passwordReset', {
    url: '/password/reset',
    templateUrl: 'views/passwordreset.html',
    controller: 'PasswordResetCtrl'
})
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
});
})
.run(function(editableOptions, $stormpath) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    $stormpath.uiRouter({
    loginState: 'login',
    defaultPostLoginState: 'main',
    forbiddenState: 'forbidden'
});
});
```

**register.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<div sp-registration-form template-url='/views/customregistrationtpl.html'></div>
</div>
```

**emailVerification.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Verify Your Account</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div sp-email-verification></div>
</div>
```

**Server app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpathExpressSdk = require('stormpath-sdk-express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// stormpath
var apiKey = require(path.join(process.env.HOME, '/.stormpath/apiKey'));
var spMiddleware = stormpathExpressSdk.createMiddleware({
  appHref: apiKey.href,
  apiKeyId: apiKey.id,
  apiKeySecret: apiKey.secret
});

// development error handler
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {

  // This will change in production since we'll be using the dist folder
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
  // This covers serving up the index page
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app')));

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
if(app.get('env') === 'production') {

  // changes it to use the optimized version for production
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: {}
    });
  });
}

// attach stormpath routes
spMiddleware.attachDefaults(app);
app.use(spMiddleware.authenticate);

// Includes all routes
var router = require('./router')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The registration URL shouldn't be requiring authentication.  Are you manually enabling authentication, or using some other feature of the library that may be requiring authentication?  I'm the author of this SDK and I'm more than happy to help.  It would be great if I could see your code, feel free to hit us up via support@stormpath.com if you want a private channel.

Comment: @robertjd Thanks for replying. Here is fine, I've just added some of my code. The only authentication feature I believe I'm using is `spMiddleware.authenticate` in the server script.